# Convolutional network insensitive to the input data variations

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have a 1 D convolutional network that is designed to predict time series data.
It has 11 layers, as it is basically designed like an AutoEncoder, with a bottleneck in between.
My normalized input comes from [-3, 3] normal distribution which outputs time series data scaled from 0 to 1.

After training and achieving desired prediction performance, I tried random noise (-0.1, 0.1) as input and observed that my network had a decent prediction. Furthermore, I created an input of all zeros (shaped like my original input), and run it thought the NN model - it again predicted something reasonable even though it had all zeros as input.

My first question is: how is that possible that the network does not react much to the input data variability?

EDIT:

***DECODER PART***

```
encoded_d = Dense(10*2, activation='linear')(_)
_ = Dense(64*2, activation='linear')(encoded_d)
_ = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.10)(_) # additional
_ = Reshape((8, 8*2))(_)
_ = Conv1D(8*2, 6, activation="linear", padding="same")(_)
_ = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(_)
_ = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.10)(_) # additional
_ = UpSampling1D(2)(_)
_ = Conv1D(16*2, 3, activation='linear')(_)
_ = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(_)

_ = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.10)(_) # additional

_ = UpSampling1D(2)(_)
output_dt = Conv1D(25, 4, activation='linear', padding='valid')(_)
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a source code to look at to understand the problem better.

Comment: Hi! Just added the decoder part, keeping in mind that the encoder is the mirrored structure of the decoder. Thank you!

Comment: 1) Why do you use `_` as name variable? Is confusing. 2) Define *decent prediction*. What do you mean by that. 3) Explain [-3, 3] normal distribution. Does this mean the sigma is 3? Maybe the input you tried are legitimate inputs after all?

Comment: Thanks for replying! 1) Using "_" is just arbitrary, I can use "x" or "z", that will not affect my output, neither will it change my question. 2) Decent prediction is that I can match my time series data with RMSE being less than 0.5. 3) Yes, it is normal distribution around mean=0 and sigmas being -3 and 3. Can you please elaborate what you meant by "legitimate input"?